# Web page anchoring links. Display indication as to which anchor the user is on

Tags: javascript, css, html, hyperlink

If we have a single page website with different divs (sections) and a header at the top with different links pointing to different anchors (divs) on the page, or of course by scrolling. How can I display a little indicator on the link that represents the anchor the user is currently on, and example is [this website](http://www.smokeybones.com/).

Comment: Post some code where you feel this does not work..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the `:hover` CSS selector (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes). You can also use a `title` attribute on the link to create a tooltip.

**UPDATE:**

I have to assume by your comment that you are referring to the "Page Indicator" in the lower right of the linked website.

To mimic that, simply change the CSS of the targeted indicator when you change the active div. Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/N39Gf/1/

Mind you, if you're willing to consider using jQuery or a similar library, animations get super simple, as does class-switching and many other operations needed to mimic this effect.

Comment: I understand what your saying but it wouldnt work for what im asking because each element is on one page and the code has to know which element is currently active so that the link corresponding to it then is highlighted.